# Python multiprocess not getting queued items

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, queue

I am passing a Queue object to a function that has been started as a Process. In the main loop, I add items to the queue expecting the process function to print out the size of the queue... but it just keeps reporting zero.

```
from queue import Queue
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

def x(q):
    while(1):
        print(q.qsize())
        sleep(1)

q = Queue()
p = Process(target=x, args=(q,))
p.start()
while 1:
    sleep(1)
    q.put(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, you need to use the Queue() from the multiprocessing library and not from the queue library.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep

def x(q):
    while(1):
        print(q.qsize())
        sleep(1)

q = Queue()
p = Process(target=x, args=(q,))
p.start()
while 1:
    sleep(1)
    q.put(1)
```

Comment: According to the documentation for the `multiprocessing.Queue.qsize` method: **Return the approximate size of the queue. Because of multithreading/multiprocessing semantics, this number is not reliable**. In other words, you do not want to be doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the info, will keep in mind, this example it would not matter, all I wanted to see was the size increase at all....